# Scroll-to-top button on mobile not working if tapping it while content still scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mobile

This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ugkw602/2/).

The scroll-to-top button is hidden by default and appears after scrolling down a bit.

**The issue** 
It does not work if tapping it while content still scrolling on mobile after swiping down, requiring a 2nd tap in this case.

**Question** 
How to make it work if tapping it while content still scrolling on mobile (on the 1st tap)?

**Code**

```
var goToTopBtn = document.getElementById("goToTop");

window.onscroll = function () {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 900 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 900) {
        $(goToTopBtn).fadeIn();
    } else {
        $(goToTopBtn).fadeOut();
    }
};

$.fn.goTo = function () {
    
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + 'px'
    }, '400');
    return this;
}

$(goToTopBtn).on("click", function (event, ui) {
    $('html').goTo();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey – Instead of `onscroll` you likely want to target the `ontouchmove` event. That should solve your problem with mobile devices

So `document.body.ontouchmove`

Edit:
The basis for this answer is that for touchscreen devices, you need to rely on `ontouchmove` instead of `onscroll`, whether you're calling it on the global `window` object, or the `document` or a DOM element like a `p-tag`

Comment: hi, thanks, however switching `window.onscroll` with `document.body.ontouchmove` modifies the behavior of the scroll event, the button not showing when required.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, I mean to say `document.ontouchmove` or `window.ontouchmove`. The basis of my answer is that you need to target the `touchmove` event and not `onscroll` for touchscreen devices. I hope that helps